# Confusion in understanding include file in my web application

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets, scriptlet

I have a problem in understanding the below mentioned code snippet.Actually it a content on .inc file. What i am confused about is what will be stored in the path variable.
will it be the path of the currently working directory or anything else...

```
<%
      String path = application.getRealPath(request.getServletPath());
      path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(java.io.File.separator));
      String dictionaryPath = path + java.io.File.separator + "dictionaries/english.txt";
      String userdict = path + java.io.File.separator + "spellchecker/dictionaries/user/user-dictionary.txt";

        int searchdepth = 50;

       boolean striphtml = true;

       String format = "javascript";
       int     suggestions = 14;
    if (request.getParameter("jsvar") != null) {
        if (!java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.\\[\\]]+$", request.getParameter("jsvar"))) {
            out.println("Invalid Jsvar");
            return;
        }
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the docs, there is no other better substitute, [context.getRealPath()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) and [request.getServletPath()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29).

BTW, how about printing that out,

```
String path = application.getRealPath(request.getServletPath());
System.out.println("path: " + path);

path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(java.io.File.separator));
System.out.println("path: " + path);

String dictionaryPath = path + java.io.File.separator + "dictionaries/english.txt";
System.out.println("dictionaryPath: " + dictionaryPath);

String userdict = path + java.io.File.separator + "spellchecker/dictionaries/user/user-dictionary.txt";
System.out.println("userdict: " + userdict);
```